# Rolling subset of data frame within for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, subset, sliding-window

Big picture explanation is I am trying to do a sliding window analysis on environmental data in R. I have PAR (photosynthetically active radiation) data for a select number of sequential dates (pre-determined based off other biological factors) for two years (2014 and 2015) with one value of PAR per day. See below the few first lines of the data frame (data frame name is "rollingpar").

```
par14           par15
1356.3242       1306.7725
NaN             1232.5637
1349.3519       505.4832
NaN             1350.4282
1344.9306       1344.6508
NaN             1277.9051
989.5620        NaN
```

I would like to create a loop (or any other way possible) to subset the data frame (both columns!) into two week windows (14 rows) from start to finish sliding from one window to the next by a week (7 rows). So the first window would include rows 1 to 14 and the second window would include rows 8 to 21 and so forth. After subsetting, the data needs to be flipped in structure (currently using the melt function in the reshape2 package) so that the values of the PAR data are in one column and the variable of par14 or par15 is in the other column. Then I need to get rid of the NaN data and finally perform a wilcox rank sum test on each window comparing PAR by the variable year (par14 or par15). Below is the code I wrote to prove the concept of what I wanted and for the first subsetted window it gives me exactly what I want.

```
library(reshape2)
par.sub=rollingpar[1:14, ]
par.sub=melt(par.sub)
par.sub=na.omit(par.sub)
par.sub$variable=as.factor(par.sub$variable)
wilcox.test(value~variable, par.sub)
#when melt flips a data frame the columns become value and variable... 
#for this case value holds the PAR data and variable holds the year 
#information
```

When I tried to write a for loop to iterate the process through the whole data frame (total rows = 139) I got errors every which way I ran it. Additionally, this loop doesn't even take into account the sliding by one week aspect. I figured if I could just figure out how to get windows and run analysis via a loop first then I could try to parse through the sliding part. Basically I realize that what I explained I wanted and what I wrote this for loop to do are slightly different. The code below is sliding row by row or on a one day basis. I would greatly appreciate if the solution encompassed the sliding by a week aspect. I am fairly new to R and do not have extensive experience with for loops so I feel like there is probably an easy fix to make this work.

```
wilcoxvalues=data.frame(p.values=numeric(0)) 
Upar=rollingpar$par14
for (i in 1:length(Upar)){
  par.sub=rollingpar[[i]:[i]+13, ]
  par.sub=melt(par.sub)
  par.sub=na.omit(par.sub)
  par.sub$variable=as.factor(par.sub$variable)
  save.sub=wilcox.test(value~variable, par.sub)
  for (j in 1:length(save.sub)){
    wilcoxvalues$p.value[j]=save.sub$p.value
  }
}
```

If anyone has a much better way to do this through a different package or function that I am unaware of I would love to be enlightened. I did try roll apply but ran into problems with finding a way to apply it to an entire data frame and not just one column. I have searched for assistance from the many other questions regarding subsetting, for loops, and rolling analysis, but can't quite seem to find exactly what I need. Any help would be appreciated to a frustrated grad student :) and if I did not provide enough information please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an `lapply` using a sequence of every 7 values through 365 days of year (last day not included to avoid single day in last grouping), all to return a dataframe list of Wilcox test p-values with *Week* indicator. Then later row bind each list item into final, single dataframe:

```
library(reshape2)
slidingWindow <- seq(1,364,by=7)
slidingWindow
# [1] 1 8 15 22 29 36 43 50 57 64 71 78 85 92 99 106 113 120 127 
# [20] 134 141 148 155 162 169 176 183 190 197 204 211 218 225 232 239 246 253 260 
# [39] 267 274 281 288 295 302 309 316 323 330 337 344 351 358

# LIST OF WILCOX P VALUES DFs FOR EACH SLIDING WINDOW (TWO-WEEK PERIODS)
wilcoxvalues <- lapply(slidingWindow, function(i) {
   par.sub=rollingpar[i:(i+13), ]
   par.sub=melt(par.sub)
   par.sub=na.omit(par.sub)
   par.sub$variable=as.factor(par.sub$variable)
   data.frame(week=paste0("Week: ", i%/%7+1, "-", i%/%7+2),
              p.values=wilcox.test(value~variable, par.sub)$p.value)
})

# SINGLE DF OF ALL P-VALUES
wilcoxdf <- do.call(rbind, wilcoxvalues)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This was exactly what I needed. I just had to adjust the slidingWindow to reflect the number of lines in my data set and add in an id.vars during the melt step but then it worked perfectly!

Comment: Great to hear! Glad I could help!